# Keyboard and getting up state on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard, state

How do I find out if the keyboard is up?

I have a UISearchbar instance which becomes the first responder.

When the keyboard appears a notification is sent out as part of the API, however I don't want to respond to this right away. I could record this in a boolean state, but that seems clunky. I'd like to know if there is a "getter" some where I can call to find out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I do it:

KeyboardStateListener.h

```
@interface KeyboardStateListener : NSObject {
    BOOL _isVisible;
}
+ (KeyboardStateListener *) sharedInstance;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, getter=isVisible) BOOL visible;
@end
```

KeyboardStateListener.m

```
#import "KeyboardStateListener.h"

static KeyboardStateListener *sharedObj;

@implementation KeyboardStateListener

+ (KeyboardStateListener *)sharedInstance
{
    return sharedObj;
}
+ (void)load
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    sharedObj = [[self alloc] init];
    [pool release];
}
- (BOOL)isVisible
{
    return _isVisible;
}
- (void)didShow
{
    _isVisible = YES;
}
- (void)didHide
{
    _isVisible = NO;
}
- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
        [center addObserver:self selector:@selector(didShow) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
        [center addObserver:self selector:@selector(didHide) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Then use this to figure out the rest:

```
KeyboardStateListener *obj = [KeyboardStateListener sharedInstance];
if ([obj isVisible]) {
    //Keyboard is up
}
```

Comment: Yes - using notifications is the only option I've been able to find. One comment though: The selector given with the observer usually takes a single input, namely the notification. So it's possibly better to have `didShow:` and the method `- (void) didShow:(NSNotification *) aNotification;` etc. instead. Also, as you say, `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` is preferred to `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`.

Answer (score 2):

The only sure way that I can think to do it as you said.  using notifications like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) 
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification 
                                           object:nil];
```

and then

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) 
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification 
                                               object:nil];
```

Other than that, you may be able to iterate through your views subviews and look for the keyboard like:

```
UIView *keyboard = nil;

for (UIView *potentialKeyboard in [myWindow subviews]) {

    // iOS 4
    if ([[potentialKeyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHostView"]) {
      potentialKeyboard = [[potentialKeyboard subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
    }                                                                                

    if ([[potentialKeyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIKeyboard"]) {
      keyboard = potentialKeyboard;
      break;
    }
  }
```

But I am not sure if this will break when the SDK changes ...

Maybe use this method and add a category to the window so that you can just always ask the window for the keyboard ... just a thought.

Comment: Thanks for this. I think you might find observing `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` is preferable to observing `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`, to be sure that the keyboard is up.

Comment: Sure, that makes sense.  I offered the other method because I figured you already understood how to use the notifications and store a BOOL in a helper class. Although the singleton on the KeyboardStateListener is a nice touch!