# iPhone:How can I learn if there is any active UIKeyboard on screen?

Tags: iphone, ios

If **any UIKeyboard** is active(opened) on the screen I want to disable some buttons on the tableview cells prevent from being clicked.

I can do this by putting booleans into textbegin editing and didfinish editing but maybe there is a more clear solution.

Is there a way to get this information from the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951201/keyboard-and-getting-up-state-on-iphone/6951400#6951400). Basically, I am using keyboardDidShow Notifications.